# How do I find which permissions using libraries I use in my Flutter project for Android

Tags: android, flutter, android-manifest

I am using a lot of libraries for my Flutter project. How do I see which permissions for Android are requested by libraries I use?

I know about the possibility that right after uploading bundle to Play Store you can see this information there under "Bundle information":
[image]

But I though there should be an easier way.

Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

If you have your application deployed in the Play Store you could go to **About this app > permissions**.

If you want to check the permissions of your application and it is not yet in Play Store I would use two methods: The first one that you already mentioned that is go to the manifest.xml file. And the second one is compile my application, use it a little bit and after that go to settings and check the requested permissions.

I hope it help you!